# php - mktime or strtotime?

Tags: php, strtotime, mktime

I'm trying to convert 2010-02 to February, 2010.  But, I keep getting December, 1969

I've tried using mktime, strtotime, and some combination of the two, but still haven't been able to do it...

This is what I tried most recently...

```
$path_title = date('F, Y', mktime(0,0,0,2,0,2010));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would be a way to do it:

```
$dateString = '2010-02';
list($year, $month) = explode('-', $dateString);
$timeStamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
echo date('F, Y', $timestamp);
```

Another way would be:

```
$dateString = '2010-02';
$timestamp = strtotime($dateString . '-01');
echo date('F, Y', $timestamp);
```

`strtotime` can't handle ambiguous dates like "2010-02", but if you make it a full date it should work.

Otherwise, you may want to look into something like [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Comment: Thanks for this. And for the link, because I think that'll be helpful in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = '2010-02';
echo date('F, Y',mktime(0,0,0,substr($str,-2),1,substr($str,0,4)));
```

You have to make sure you use valid values to `mktime()`.  In your example that you edited into the question, you have `0` as the day, which is effectively the first day minus one, which puts you into the previous month.